# When ever I suspend my ubuntu 23.04, I log out of user (after some sort of error)

Tags: gnome, suspend, logout

Since 4 days whenever I suspend my pc ( either power button or directly closing laptop physically), when I turn on next time, the user is logged out and all running programs got killed. I am doing it since weeks and the problem comes just now. When I log in, the first screen becomes blank and then it is written

```
[ 5049.219977] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Error of this Agent is repoted
```

How to solve it ( I am using ubuntu 23.04) ?